# I'm outa headings and don't know what to do

Tags: html

What do I do if I've already used up all available (6) heading tags? I read somewhere that it's bad practice to use the same heading tag more than once. But using a p tag for something that needs to be a heading isn't much better... I could just use the same heading tag but then I'd feel dirty. I need maor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not bad practice at all to use the same header tag multiple times. The different header tags indicate different levels in the hierarchy of headers, and not different individual headers.

Comment: Now that makes sense. Thanks heaps @duplode :-D

Comment: Sorry it took me two years to accept this answer. I just randomly remembered my login details for this account. Now I'm going through my old questions, accepting what needs to be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

You could always just start setting incremented font sizes. I mean its not ideal but it'll be pretty close